# Upgrade Indy9 to Indy10

Tags: delphi, indy

I  want to upgrade my application from Indy 9 to 10 with Delphi 2007.
There is a lot of issues in this, I have read the indy doc about changes but I still need advise. This won't compile as ReadString is not found.

```
vCmdHead := FTCPClient.ReadString(16);
```

where FTCPClient is of type TIdTCPClient. vCmdHead is a structure that contains a command as a string. What method could I use instead ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
      {$IFDEF INDY10}
      ALine := IdTCPClient.IOHandler.ReadString(16);
      {$ELSE}
      Aline := IdTCPClient.ReadString(16);
      {$ENDIF}
```

Something like this

Comment: Thanks! At least it compiles fine with this. Probably not my last question about Indy10 :)